# Hover + Mousemove, how could I reduce the repeated code?

Tags: jquery, hover, mousemove

I looked at stackoverflow, and I am not a programmer, I am sure that I am missing some basic knowledge, and jquery reference website it isn't helping.

I have to use both mouseove and hover, to detect if a mouse it is moving on top of an image (that could have an animation). My problem is that I want to reduce the same code that I use for doing the *mystuff*, but at the same time I need the alternative for when the mouse leaves to do the *myotherstuff*.

How should I write the code?

```
$("#central .img").mousemove(
   function(){*mystuff*}
);

$("#central .img").hover(
   function(){*mystuff*}
   ,function(){*myotherstuff*}
);
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: remove mousemove, after all if it's going to do the same thing

Comment: No, it is not doing the same thing. Like I said I have an animation, and it happens that when the mouse is still, and the animation is moving, the hover doesn't work. The mouse isn't detected by the browser/js as hovering, even if I move the mouse afterwards on top of the image. I have to go out of the image and hover again, for this reason I need both, because I do not want that my users have to move the mouse away and hover the image to visualise *mystuff*

Comment: This code seems to work OK. (http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/YtCCK/). Is it not working? What is happening? Can you post some sample code?

Comment: I cannot post, because I am working on it and you will see just weird things happening because I am modifying the code as we are speaking. it is working but I need both mouseenter and hover. I just need to optimise the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can name your function and reuse it.

```
function myfunction(){*mystuff*}
$("#central .img").mousemove(myfunction);

$("#central .img").hover(
   myfunction
   ,function(){*myotherstuff*}
);
```

Comment: Thank you, it was this that I was looking for. I wasn't sure how to handle the bind function(){} of jquery to transform in a normal function and still having the "hover" out with the .hover functionality.